# User-assigned strings to select active windows

Tags: windows

I would like to be able to type a **string or a keyword** (such as "news" or "report") and assign it to an open window. I can then recall this window using that keyword or string.

For example, say I have a document open in Word called `report.docx` in one window, a website open in Chrome with news (e.g. `cnn.com`), and some other third application in a third window.

I would like to have a program that I can use to open a **small text window** centered on the screen (similar to [Launchy's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchy)) where I could type a hotstring and tell this program which window to associate the hotstring with.

Then later, at anytime, I could invoke this program again (i.e. bring up the text window) to type the hotstring again and bring back the window that I associated with the hotstring.

In the example above, I could assign the string `"report"` to the Word window with the document "report.docx", the hotstring `"news"` to the chrome window with `"cnn.com"`, etc.

Is there any tool that does this on Windows? Perhaps using [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)?

## Update:

The following script allows the user to assign numbers to windows using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+`number`, and then recall them with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+number. I am hoping this script can serve as a basis for what I am aiming to do.

In particular it would be nice to have a **hotkey** that brings up a **text box** where the user can type the **string or keywords** when assigning or recalling windows. There should be **one** hotkey for assigning strings to windows, and **another** hotkey for recalling windows.

A particular feature of the script below is that it remembers the window size and location.

```
Loop 10 
{ 
   i := A_Index - 1 
   HotKey ^%i%,DynHotkey 
   HotKey !%i%, DynHotkey 
} 
Exit 

DynHotkey: 
   StringRight i, A_ThisHotKey, 1 
   StringLeft what, A_ThisHotKey, 1 
   var := var%i% 
   IfEqual what, ^ 
   { 
   WinGet var%i%, ID, A
   WinGetPos, X%i%, Y%i%, Width%i%, Height%i%, A
   } 
   ;Else IfEqual what,!, WinMinimizeAll
   Else
   { 
   XX:=X%i%
   YY:=Y%i%
   WW:=Width%i%
   HH:=Height%i%
   WinActivate ahk_id %var%
   WinMove, A,, XX, YY, WW, HH
   }
Return
```

Comment: Yes. AutoHotkey can do this effortlessly! I am busy right now, but later I can whip of a script that will do exactly what you want. :)

Comment: Thanks iglvzx! That would be fantastic. I have a script in AutoHotkey that may help with this a bit too. I'll update the post with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a basic AutoHotkey script for assigning names to windows and then activating them by name:

```
;Requires AutoHotkey_L

array := Object() ;associative array of name:window

#!n:: ;Windows+Alt+N
InputBox, name, , Set a name for the active window:
WinGet, window, ID, A
array[name] := window
Exit

#n:: ;Windows+N
InputBox, name, , Enter the name of a window to activate:
window := array[name]
WinActivate, ahk_id %window%
Exit
```

Obviously, it is not a complete program. It can be improved by testing if a name or window already exists in the array, etc... But functionality wise, this is as simple as it gets! :)